# Basis of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. Nikolay Gusev's course on Stepic.

Tags: linear-algebra

The exercise I'm given is:
Consider the space $\mathbb{R}^{n}, n\geqslant3$. 
Let's take the column $(110...000)^{T}$ and by shifting all elements down by one cell we have $(011...000)^{T}, (001...000)^{T},..., (000...110)^{T}, (000...011)^{T}$. 
Now we have $n-1$ vectors, since we've applied $n-1$ steps. For sure these vectors cannot be a basis in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, we need one more vector, for example $(100...001)^{T}$ (trying to imagine this vector as a circle).
Any basis in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ consists of $n$ elements, so it's sufficient to check that these vectors are linearly independent. **Let's find $\alpha_{1}..\alpha_{n}$:** $$\alpha_{1}\begin{pmatrix}
 1   \\
 1   \\
 0   \\
 ...  \\
 0    \\
 0   \\
 0 
\end{pmatrix} +\alpha_{2}\begin{pmatrix}
 0   \\
 1   \\
 1   \\
 ...  \\
 0    \\
 0   \\
 0 
\end{pmatrix}+\alpha_{3}\begin{pmatrix}
 0   \\
 0   \\
 1   \\
 ...  \\
 0    \\
 0   \\
 0 
\end{pmatrix} ... +\alpha_{n-2}\begin{pmatrix}
 0   \\
 0   \\
 0   \\
 ...  \\
 1    \\
 1   \\
 0 
\end{pmatrix} +\alpha_{n-1}\begin{pmatrix}
 0   \\
 0   \\
 0   \\
 ...  \\
 0    \\
 1   \\
 1 
\end{pmatrix} +\alpha_{n}\begin{pmatrix}
 1   \\
 0   \\
 0   \\
 ...  \\
 0    \\
 0   \\
 1 
\end{pmatrix}=0$$
And  I don't understand the following step where he says **"We end up with a system of linear equations of the form"**:$$\left\{
\begin{array}{rcl}
 \alpha_{1}+\alpha_{n}= 0 \\
 \alpha_{1}+\alpha_{2} = 0 \\
 \alpha_{2}+\alpha_{3} = 0 \\
 ... \\
 \alpha_{n-1}+\alpha_{n} = 0
\end{array}
\right.$$
Why do we have exactly this system? Why do we need to sum every following pair?
By the way, maybe it's useful: by doing that he gets $\alpha_{1}=-\alpha_{n}; \alpha_{2}=\alpha_{n}; \alpha_{3}=-\alpha_{n}...$. I'm sure I skip a logic step and it's a simple question, but it is what it is.

Comment: In the equation of column vectors you wrote above, the right side must be a column of zeroes(a vector) and not the number 0. So, then we can equate the entries of the sum of the columns on the left hand side to the corresponding entry on the right hand side, but on the right hand side all entries are 0. This gives you that system of equations.

Comment: Thank you, @Aman. I've seen the answer by writing the right hand side as a zero-column.